# Should I use Realm for React Native?

Tags: react-native, realm

can I have your feedback on @realm/react? I used SQLite in my previous projects. Now I want to use Realm because of its simplicity and context feature. However, I have concerns about the future. The number of downloads per week is 3000. I'm really not sure if I should use Realm. Is it worth using or should I go with SQLite?

Comment: While the question is clear, it's asking for our opinion when we have zero knowledge of your use case. How could we tell you if it's a good option or not when we don't know what you're doing with it. Realm may be perfect solution for some applications and be not be for others.

Answer (score -1):

SQLite is complex that is why the majority use Realm in their first projects but when the projects get more complex and large scale, SQLite coupled with Room is the better option. Realm can be a good choice if you have an application with a very simple database. But in reality, When the application starts to expand and manipulations in the database become more serious than just putting and getting data from the table, you will understand the complexity of NoSQL databases.

Realm combined with App Services is a modern and robust mobile database solution, wherein it is superior to SQLite with Core Data and/or Room in many aspects. It allows users to build cross-platform, offline-first applications backed by the entire Realm and MongoDB Atlas cloud platform.

Comment: Can you clarify how a *majority* was determined that move from Realm to the platform you're suggesting? Was that from a research study that's documented? Can you also clarify - *putting and getting data from the table* - from my understanding, NoSQL document databases like Realm/Atlas store data in [non-tabular](https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained) documents (e.g. there are no tables). Just trying to gain an understanding of your recommendation when we don't what the use case is and why Realm cannot be used for complex queries and manipulations. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).